# .Htaccess - Remove trailing slash, whilst all pages still go to index.php

Tags: apache, .htaccess, mod-rewrite

I've searched over previously asked questions but none have the same problem as me. I'm wanting to remove the trailing slash, whilst still sending all pages to index.php (or if the file actually exists, use that.)

I'd like a solution that I don't have to fiddle with between server and localhost.

So `localhost/pages/to/file/` and `http://example.com/pages/to/file/`, go to `... /pages/to/file`

My current htaccess file:

```
RewriteEngine on

# removes www.
RewriteCond %{HTTP_HOST} ^www\.(.*)$ [NC]
RewriteRule ^(.*)$ http://%1%{REQUEST_URI} [R=301,QSA,NC,L]

# if file exists, ignore the index.php re-write
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f

# send everything to index.php
RewriteRule . index.php
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Give the following a try:

```
RewriteEngine on

# Remove the trailing slash, if not in a directory
# DirectorySlash off can be used instead.
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d
RewriteRule ^(.*)/$ /$1 [L,R=301]

# Remove www. (generic method with HTTPS support)
RewriteCond %{HTTP_HOST} ^www\.
RewriteCond %{HTTPS}s ^on(s)|off
RewriteCond http%1://%{HTTP_HOST} ^(https?://)(www\.)?(.+)$
RewriteRule ^ %1%3%{REQUEST_URI} [R,L]

# Send everything (except existing files) to index.php
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
RewriteRule ^ index.php [L]
```

If this works for you, change the `R` flag to `R=301` to make the redirect permanent.

Comment: This causes a redirect loop on directories. Is there anyway to fix this? Fixed this using "DirectorySlash Off"

Comment: Is there anyway to merge the trailing slash and removal of www, like Sumurai8 has done below? If done, this is the perfect answer. 3: I figure the less RewriteRule's the better.

Comment: In my mind, it isn't the greatest thing to have less rules. This is the most precise method. Combining everything into one rule may be possible, but not always recommended. I do understand that there is the issue of possible double redirects, but that should not occur often, as search engines will be indexing the stuff user's a redirected to. So, having two rules really makes no difference.

Comment: (Sorry, bad typing there. Should have read "as search engines will be indexing the stuff *users are* redirected to".)

Answer (score 0):

You can add an extra condition to your existing rule to remove www and remove any trailing slash in that rule too.

```
RewriteEngine on

# removes www. and trailing slash
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_URI} /$ [OR]
RewriteCond %{HTTP_HOST} ^www\.(.*)$ [NC]
RewriteRule ^(.*?)/?$ http://%1/$1 [R=301,QSA,NC,L]

# if file exists, ignore the index.php re-write
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f

# send everything to index.php
RewriteRule . index.php
```

See [the documentation](http://httpd.apache.org/docs/current/mod/mod_rewrite.html) for clarification.

Answer (score 0):

Have a separate rule for removal of trailing slash:

```
RewriteEngine on

# removes www.
RewriteCond %{HTTP_HOST} ^www\.(.+)$ [NC]
RewriteRule ^ http://%1%{REQUEST_URI} [R=301,NE,L]

RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
RewriteCond %{THE_REQUEST} \s/+(.*?)[^/][?\s]
RewriteRule [^/]$ %{REQUEST_URI}/ [L,NE,R=301]

# if file/directory exists, ignore the index.php re-write
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d
# send everything to index.php
RewriteRule . index.php [L]
```

Comment: What does the !-d do?

Comment: `!-d` means request is not for a directory.